# Flask handling a PDF as its own page

Tags: python, pdf, web, flask

For my personal website, I want to have a separate page just for my résumé, which is a PDF. I've tried multiple ways, but I can't figure out how to get flask to handle a PDF.

Comment: Can you get the web server to serve the file statically (like you're probably doing for your `/static` files anyway). If so, can you just make a link in your Flask app to the static file?

Answer (score 51):

A note for anyone that came to this question because they're trying to serve PDF files from a database with Flask. Embedding a PDF when the file is stored on a database isn't as simple as when it's in the static folder. You have to use the `make_response` function and give it the appropriate headers so the browser knows what to do with your binary PDF data, rather than just returning it from the view function like normal. Here's some pseudocode to help:

```
from flask import make_response

@app.route('/docs/<id>')
def get_pdf(id=None):
    if id is not None:
        binary_pdf = get_binary_pdf_data_from_database(id=id)
        response = make_response(binary_pdf)
        response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/pdf'
        response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = \
            'inline; filename=%s.pdf' % 'yourfilename'
        return response
```

You can change the Content-Disposition from 'inline' to 'attachment' if you want the file to download rather than display in the browser. You could also put this view in a subdomain, e.g. docs.yourapp.com rather than yourapp.com/docs. The last step is to actually embed this document in the browser. On any page you'd like, just use rawrgulmuffin's strategy:

```
<embed src="/docs/pdfid8676etc" width="500" height="375">
```

You could even make the src dynamic with a Jinja2 template. Let's put this in doc.html (note the curly brackets):

```
<embed src="/docs/{{doc_id}}">
```

Then in a view function, you just return the rendered template with the appropriate doc_id:

```
from flask import render_template

@app.route('/<id>')
def show_pdf(id=None):
    if id is not None:
        return render_template('doc.html', doc_id=id)
```

This embeds a document the user requested from a database with a simple GET request. Hope this helps anyone working with lots of PDFs in a database!

Comment: make_response gives an error : TypeError: 'file' object is not callable | what could be wrong ?

Answer (score 19):

You can use flask `send_file` or `send_static_file` function in **5** lines:

```
from flask import send_file, current_app as app

@app.route('/show/static-pdf/')
def show_static_pdf():
    with open('/path/of/file.pdf', 'rb') as static_file:
        return send_file(static_file, attachment_filename='file.pdf')
```

[This snippet link](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/32/) is helpful

Also can use `send_from_directory` if you want send file from certain directory:

```
from flask import send_from_directory, current_app as app

@app.route('/show/PDFs/')
def send_pdf():
    return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], 'file.pdf')
```

[read more](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.send_from_directory) about `send_from_directory`

Comment: It would be better to use `with` to open a file, which makes sure the file is closed after using.

Comment: I know this is years later but my code is                        ```server_bp.route('/resume')
def resume():
    return send_file('static/pdf/resume.pdf', attachment_filename='resume.pdf')
``` which works fine. I found this answer the most helpful but I am not sure that ```with open``` is how you want it. Their browser will display the pdf. You do not want your server opening the file.

Comment: Hi @DavidFrick, in many scenarios we made file content before sending to clients, and in some conditions we don't store content in real file, instead use buffer or something like BytesIO

Comment: @M.javid that makes perfect sense then! Side note: Would you know any way of displaying the pdf as a container within the page so to speak? This solution, at least for me, makes the browser download the pdf and open as a new page, losing the ability to navigate around my website.

Answer (score 11):

You have two options. You can either render a template that uses a static PDF file or render a template that generates a PDF. I'd personally go with the first option.

[This SO question is dedicated to how to write an HTML page that returns a PDF. You can use this in your jinja2 template.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/recommended-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html)

Here's a quick and dirty way to get it done.

```
<embed src="http://yoursite.com/the.pdf" width="500" height="375">
```

Or, you can create a jinja2 template which sets all the headers required to return a PDF and then say,

```
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img.png', _external=True) }}" />
```

with a view function called static that returns the pdf.

[You can read more about the second option at this flask snippet](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/68/)

Comment: With the 'quick and dirty way', can the src be just the pdf document in the root of my program's folder or does it have to link to a URL? Thanks!

Comment: It can be just the pdf. [you can use relative paths from whatever folder the template is called from](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7503130/relative-path-or-url-for-html-src-and-href-attributes). So if your structure is `app->templates->PDFTemplate.html` and your file is in `app->pdf.pdf` then you can say `src="../pdf.pdf"`.

Answer (score 5):

I know it's quite late, but I just found the easiest way and it's not among those.

Just **redirect to the file's path** as a static file, with any hyperlink:

```
"/docs/sample.pdf" #the browser will take care about showing it
```

Or, if you want a maybe cleaner way... I just made a flask page for the pdfs like this:

```
@app.route('/pdf/') #the url you'll send the user to when he wants the pdf
def pdfviewer():
    return redirect("/docs/sample.pdf") #the pdf itself
```

...which I guess is kinda like giving a variable name to the pdf link (?), and also should be easier to adapt if I need to send the user to different pdfs depending on a variable.

I'm thinking something in this lines:

```
@app.route('/pdf<number>') #passing variable through the url
def pdfviewer(number):
    if number == 1: #pdf depending on that variable
        return redirect("/docs/sample1.pdf")
    elif number == 2:
        return redirect("/docs/sample1.pdf")
    ...
    else:
        return "Hey I don't have such pdf" #basic html page as default
```

BTW: I'm working on pythonAnywhere, so I had to first define the path to the `static files` in the Web tab, so I could show static files to the user.

Comment: Then you can add load parameters by adding to the end. For example `#view=fit` to load seeing entire page. For full list see this https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf

Answer (score 1):

If your trying to do your typical

```
<a href="path/doc.pdf">My Resume</a>
```

where the user clicks on the link and the pdf is downloaded, you need to put your documents in your static folder.

then you end up with something like:

```
<a href="../static/doc.pdf">My Resume</a>
```