# provide a link to download file

Tags: python, flask

I am using python flask. I want to provide a url in template which varies in filename.

## Folder structure:

project_folder/download/pdf <-images in this folder

url_for('download/pdf/filenameXYZ.pdf') didnt worked.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to return static content you should tell Flask that you want static content :)

As you can see in this example: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/jquery/?highlight=static

You need something like this:

```
url_for('static', filename='download/pdf/filenameXYZ.pdf')
```

Comment: <a href='/static/download/pdf/finelameXYZ.pdf'>Download</a> works...
Can't I put the download folder as in level of static folder ???

Comment: Yes, as long as your downloads folder is a subdirectory of your static folder it should work ilke that. Alternatively, you can also add the redirect in your webserver somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

[url_for takes a flask function that has a route associated with it and any parameters you want to pass to that view](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.url_for). What url_for will do is return the URL path for that function.

If you want to display a PDF then you need to render a template which contains a HTML  or  tag. [There's actually a bunch of different ways to handle this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18281433/flask-handling-a-pdf-as-its-own-page/18281582#18281582)

An example that you could use in a template is

```
<embed src="/download/pdf/the.pdf" width="500" height="375">
```

the main point is that url_for doesn't take a file path.