# Python Flask send pdf file using decoded request.content

Tags: python, flask, sendfile, x-sendfile

I'm having great difficulty downloading files from a sharepoint server in my flask application.

I'm making a get request to the sharepoint api to get the file and it looks successful when I print my download object

[image]

But I cant figure out how to decode the content and then send for download

I've tried the below

```
return send_file(BytesIO(download.content), mimetype='application/pdf', as_attachment=True, attachment_filename='test.pdf')
```

But when i try to open it looks like it hasn't decoded properly

[image: send]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flask handling a PDF as its own page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18281433/flask-handling-a-pdf-as-its-own-page)

Comment: can you share the code where you make the request to the sharepoint api?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using `requests` module and the shortcut method `get` to  make the get request, just returning the  content along with the status_code and headers should do the trick

```
return download.content, download.status_code, download.headers.items()
```

Comment: wow, it worked. I swear i tried this combination! minor problem now any idea how to force the popup windows file name?

Comment: is it something to do with 'Content-Disposition': 'attachment',

Comment: perfect ```download.headers['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment; filename={file_name}'```