# Set an anchor element's href relative to the current URI?

Tags: html

Im on the page:

```
example.com/news
```

It's a list of news articles. Is it possible to set links on each news article and take into account the current url?

```
<a href="the-article">link to something</a>
```

The above will link to:

```
example.com/news/article
```

Or will I need to get the entire route and specify that in the link?

The url could be anything eg. /products so I do not want to hardcode it in.

Comment: `<a href="/news/article">link to something</a>`

Comment: @shennan this will go to example.com/article

Comment: @Oday nope, it'll go to example.com/news/article

Comment: before editing the comment :)

Comment: @shennan this does not take into account the current url

Comment: @Oday you commented 1 min ago, I edited 2 mins ago :-)

Comment: @panthro Its an absolute path for the domain

Comment: Configure the server to redirect `example.com/news` to `example.com/news/`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Relative path or url for html src and href attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7503130/relative-path-or-url-for-html-src-and-href-attributes)

Comment: This post might as well be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005079/absolute-vs-relative-urls

Comment: Please not that, this question is not a duplicate of above linked. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Browser replaces the part comes after the last `/` of open page's URL to produce absolute URL from relative path. Either:

- Use filenames at the end of your URLs (like `news/index.html`)
- Use `/` at the end of your URLs (like `news/`)
- Use absolute URLs instead of relative paths for `href` (like `example.com/news/the-article`)
- Set a base element to guide the browser to add last `/`

  ```html
  <base href="http://example.com/news/the-article/" />
  ```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to take into account the current path, use the page name directly in the href attribute:

If you are on example.com/news and used an href value of "article", the URL becomes example.com/news/article.

If you need to reference pages on the root directory, precede the page name with slash '/', href="/article".

Comment: I've tried using <a href="article"> but it just goes back to site route: example.com/article where it should be example.com/news/article

Answer (score 0):

Make it relative?

```
<a href="./article">link to something</a>
```

For some browsers/DOCTYPE, you may have to use this in conjunction with the [base tag element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base), which will need to be added to every page that utilises relative paths:

```
<base href="http://www.example.com/news">
```

Comment: this just goes back to example.com/article